# Can't set field name when creating word document

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba, field

I'm using Office 365. My Access VBA code is creating a Word document. I can add a field onto a table within the document. But when I try to set the Name of the field or the text within the field, it is bombing out. Here's my code:

```
Dim WordApp As New Word.Application
Dim WordDoc As New Word.Document
Dim fField As Word.FormField

Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = True
WordApp.Activate
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
WordDoc.Select
' Here I set up some header text, then I set WordRange to be at the end of the document
Set WordTable = WordDoc.Tables.Add(WordRange, 6, 4)

With WordDoc.Tables(1)
    Set oRange = .Cell(1, 2).Range
    Set fField = ActiveDocument.FormFields.Add(Range:=oRange, Type:=wdFieldFormTextInput)
'
' If I do it either of the two ways below, I get a 'Runtime error 91: Object Variable or With block variable not set'
'
fField.Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = "FirstName"
fField.Range.Text = "FirstName"
'
' The same error comes up when I try to
'
fField.Name = "FirstName"
End With
```

I've seen examples for both of these approaches on websites, they all seem to say that this will work.

Do note that I've chopped out a bunch of stuff that also populates the table, but I don't think it has any affect on what I'm doing here.

It bombs out on either line:

```
fField.Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = "FirstName"
```

or

```
fField.Range.Text = "firstName"
```

(I only use one of those at a time, I comment out the other). Both of these result in the following error.

> Runtime error 91: Object Variable or With block variable not set.

While waiting for a response, I copied all of my code into a temp routine and I got rid of all the extraneous stuff. I found that when I try to put the field into a table, it bombs (at the lines mentioned above), but when I create the field outside of a table, it can set the text and the name of the field with no problem! Any ideas how I can get this to work inside of a table???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to address the Cell first:
    `.Cell(1, 2).Range.FormFields(1).Result = "Joseph"` and
    `.Cell(1, 2).Range.FormFields(1).Name = "FirstName"`
rather than
    `fField.Text`.